# Несколько вопросов о generic, кастинге и избегании raw type

Tags: java, generics

Добрый день.

Возникла задача:

на входе Object, однако я знаю (проверил ранее: o.getClass().isArray()), что в нем может содержаться массив любого типа, либо примитивного, либо нет (int[], Object[], SomeClass[] и т.д.).

Сначала я решил задачу не избежав raw type:

```
static List getListRaw(Class clazz, Object o){
    if (clazz==int[].class){
        return IntStream.of((int[]) o).boxed().collect(Collectors.toList());
    } else {
        return Stream.of((Object[])o).collect(Collectors.toList());
    }
}
```

Кастинг, создание массивов  остальных 7 примитивов и проверка на массив опущены.

Однако понятно, что этот способ плох:

```
Object intArray = new int[]{1, 2, 3};
List<String> rawArray = getListRaw(intArray.getClass(), intArray);

rawArray.add("oops");
rawArray.forEach(System.out::println);
```

Типичная ошибка неправильного использования дженериков.

Захотелось сделать обобщенный метод примерно с такой сигнатурой:

```
<T> List<T> getList(Class<T> clazz, Object o)
```

И тут возникли проблемы, я не знаю как это сделать.

Если я пишу примерно так:

```
static <T> List<T> getList(Class<T> clazz, Object o){

    if (clazz==int[].class){
         //не компилируется
        //return IntStream.of((int[]) o).boxed().collect(Collectors.toList());
        return (List<T>) Arrays.asList((int[]) o);

    } else {
        //return (List<T>) Stream.of((Object[])o).collect(Collectors.toList());
        return (List<T>) Arrays.asList((Object[])o);
    }
}
```

То следующие проблемы:

1) Если тип не примитивный (getList(nonPrimitive.getClass(), nonPrimitive);), то возвращается лист объектов, которые нужно вручную кастить, чего хотелось бы избежать (если вместо nonPrimitive.getClass() подавать ClassName.class, то все работает, но у меня нет ClassName в общем случае)

2) Если тип примитивный вышеописанный способ возвращает List из одного элемента в который кладет array, причем этот List тоже Object. Способ через IntStream не работает так как возвращает конкретный лист int, который не присваивается на List < T >

Впринципе, для моей задачи raw type - не страшно, но чисто академический интерес - как решить задачу максимально корректно?

Уточняю ( не трогаем примитивы - это частный случай):

```
    Object pojoArray = new Pojo[]{new Pojo(1), new Pojo(2)};

    getList(pojoArray.getClass(), pojoArray).forEach(o -> {
       //o надо кастить но я не знаю на что    
    });

    getList(Pojo.class, pojoArray).forEach(o -> {
        //o не надо кастить  но у меня нет информации о Pojo.class    
    });
```

Comment: А для чего нужен подобный функционал? Просто интересно.Ну или может совместными усилиями более правильный подход найдём. :)

Comment: @rjhdby у меня на входе некоторая структура данных, которая возвращает данные в Object. Я рефлекшеном создаю объекты своих Pojo. Впринципе, setField работает и на raw type, но, как я и сказал, задача представляет собой академический интерес.

Comment: А к чему вы хотите кастить `o` в `forEach`? В смысле, если вы в теле лямбды можете написать `(Pojo)o`, то вы можете передать `Pojo.class` в `getList`.

Comment: @zRrr это просто пример - когда все работает. В общем случае у меня есть Object o. и его тип я могу получить только как o.getClass.

Comment: Вообщем, нельзя. Type erasure - дженериков в рантайме нет -  T компилируется в object, а при их вызове, компилятор подставляет кастование. Т.е. если я передаю как тип getClass, то при вызове обобщенного метода в рантайме возвращает Class<? extends Object>.